# 「目次」見出しを中央寄せにして間に2, 3文字の空白を加えたい

Tags: latex

論文をLaTeXで書いています（ドキュメントクラスはjlreqでオプションはbookです）。
ファイルの構成は章ごとにファイルを分けてmerge.texで一つに纏めるという方法です。

merge.texで`\tableofcontents`を打つと目次が表示されるのですが私好みの表示ではありません。
そのため、それを修正しようと考えています。
具体的には、『目次』という表記を『目　　次』というようにして中央寄せにすることです。

そこで、[こちら](https://qiita.com/shohirose/items/52f778ebd21f8e5f5c0e#%E7%9B%AE%E6%AC%A1%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%93%E8%A3%81%E3%82%92%E8%AA%BF%E6%95%B4tocloft)のサイトを参考にtocloftパッケージを読み込んだ上でmerge.texに下記を追加してみました。

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\null}
```

すると中央寄せにはなったのですが、『第〇章』の箇所と章名が重なってしまいました。
また、間にいれる空白は解決しておりません。

何か方法ありますでしょうか。
ご教示お願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tocloftパッケージは日本語を想定していないのではないでしょうか。jlreqの目次の見出しを変更するだけであれば、tocloftを利用するまでもなく`\contentsname`を再定義するだけで十分そうです。

```
%#!uplatex
\documentclass[book]{jlreq}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{%
  \makebox[\linewidth]{\hfill 目\hspace{2zw}次\hfill}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{序章}
\chapter{何らかのコンテンツ}

\end{document}
```

[image: 組版結果]

なお、目次の見出しだけを変更すると他の見出しとのデザインの統一感がなくなりそうな気もしますので、全体のデザインの均整は別途よくご検討されることをおすすめします。